# *ngFor - array of image urls - not working

Tags: angular, data-binding, ngfor

I'm tying to show array of images via `*ngFor`. it supposed to show all different images but instead its just show only one and first image of array.

So far:

```
private localImg:any = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.localImg = [     
     {id:0,name:"img0",url:'assets/img/img0.png'},
     {id:1,name:"img0",url:'assets/img/img1.png'},
     {id:2,name:"img0",url:'assets/img/img2.png'},
     {id:3,name:"img0",url:'assets/img/img3.png'},
     {id:4,name:"img0",url:'assets/img/img4.png'},     
      ]
      console.log("image", this.localImg);
  }

<div class="container-fluid" *ngFor="let img of localImg">
   <div class="row imagetiles">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <img [src]='img.url' class="img-responsive">
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried to get images using `[src]='img.url'` and changed to `[src]='img.id'` and `name` but no luck.

Or please suggest me any other shorter and easy solution.

Thank you so much for your solutions.

Comment: it shows all 5 in here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fgdlbg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: have you check your stackblitz?  its not working. not able to see image.

Comment: hi @SunilSingh can u pls edit above stackblitz. i dont understand your suggestion. you mean i should mention img.img0 like that?

Comment: @worstCoder that because url are invalid. If u provide a valid urls then u should get the all images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a new project with this implementation:

App.component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      imgList: any[] = []

      constructor(){
        this.imgList = [
          {id: 1, path:"./assets/1.jpeg"},
          {id: 2, path:"./assets/2.jpeg"},
          {id: 3, path:"./assets/3.jpeg"}
        ];
      }
    }
```

App.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let i of imgList">
  <img [src]="i.path" style="width:100px">
</div>
```

Struct of the project:

[image]

and this is the result:

[image]

Since the only problem I see is the path, are you sure that the images path is correct? Also, are the images valid?

Comment: you're exactly right . path is the problem now fixed. thank you

Comment: i am unable to understand that if actual problem was path then how you were able to see one image.

Comment: I just guessed. I even tought that the problem could've been the fact that you were cycling, in the html with an iter called `img`, and maybe that name could've broken something in Angular (maybe being a protective workd, or something like that). Anyway, adding the `./` at the start mean that angular will look starting from the absolute path, and not the relative. and the absolute path starts by `src` folder

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the problem is that you're referencing your paths by doing this:

```
url:'assets/img/img0.png'
```

instead of:

```
url:'./assets/img/img0.png'
```